# Why are Firefox specific attributes visible in Firebug

Tags: css, firefox, firebug

The Style Panel in Firebug shows the following image:

[image: Style Panel]

My CSS definition in question (for div#shell ul.tabs li) does NOT have the first five attributes specified (i.e. those starting with -moz*).  Why are these inserted by Firebug when I have "Show User Agent CSS" and "Expand Shorthand Properties" UNCHECKED?

I am on Win 7, FF 10.0.2, Firebug 1.10.0a5.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `border` shorthand sets those properties.

Comment: Thanks Boris.  Why are they shown in Firebug when other Mozilla-specific settings are not?

Comment: I have no idea on that...  I thought Firebug just showed all CSS properties that are set that Gecko parsed!